# Menu icons is not displayed when using ActionBarActivity in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When I using simple Activity, my menu icons was displayed perfectly. But as I want to use ActionBarActivity instead of Activity, icons gone.
This is my menu/main.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:satra="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        satra:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        satra:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/myLocationButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/location_disabled"
        android:title="@string/my_location"
        satra:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:icon="@drawable/drawer_disabled"
        android:title="@string/drawer_menu"
        satra:showAsAction="always"/>
     <item
        android:id="@+id/configButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/gear"
        android:title="@string/config"
        satra:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

The last item with id of configButton that its showAsAction set to "never" is displayed in menu and so its icon is not displayed. But the ones that in actionbar, their icons is displaying.
I don't know what is wrong with it.

And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what it means by `satra` here??

Comment: I want my app to work from android 10 to 19 and my actionbar works with these versions. After I searched a lot, I got that in order to got it work in lower android versions I have to declare satra at top of page and use it for showAsAction.

Answer (score 0):

Remove satra and replace it with android n try this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/myLocationButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/location_disabled"
    android:title="@string/my_location"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:icon="@drawable/drawer_disabled"
    android:title="@string/drawer_menu"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/configButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/gear"
    android:title="@string/config"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
```